# python current working directory changed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file called `test.py` which usually opens a text file `test.txt`

These files are both located in the same folder. Usually, when I use this test.py file, it reads test.txt

However, only very recently, when running the `test.py`, it would tell me that `Errno 2, no file or directory`, when the text file is obviously there. When running the cwd function it would tell me that my current working directory was the P5 folder which is located in another folder. A solution to my problem would very much be appreciated!

```
with open('test.txt','r') as test:
    print(test.read())
```

this is the entire `test.py`. I've identified the problem, and it has to do with Atom editor. For some reason the cwd is always `My Documents`?

Comment: Can you please share your `test.py` code? We'll need your code to understand your problem. Please also share the exact command you're using to run the script (even if that seems obvious).

Comment: hi Dave, I'd like to thank you for your answer, ive updated the question as above, and have also noticed that it had to do with Atom. However, i've never had this problem with it.

Comment: out of curiosity, you don't happen to have a copy of `test.py` in the `P5` folder?

Comment: Probably you have called the script from outside your intended folder.

Comment: @fsp the script works fine outside of atom, but while inside it runs from inside the folder it originates from. This problem has only occured in the last hour or so which is very surprising to me.

`D:\Jayden Luu\Documents
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Jayden Luu\Documents\Python\multi\test.py", line 6, in <module>
    with open('test.txt','r') as test:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.txt'
[Finished in 0.091s]`


The test.py file is in D:\Jayden Luu\Documents\Python\multi

Comment: are you in the `multi` folder when you call `test.py`?

Comment: @Harpal yes, i am. i am in the `multi` folder.

Comment: When you type `dir` in the command window do you see `test.py` and `test.txt` in the list